# Cannot do su in CentOs

Tags: centos, active-directory, authentication, su

I have troubles with `su` on system that is attached to Active directory.

```
[user1@host_test ~]$ su - username
Password:
su: Permission denied
[user1@host_test ~]$
```

But i can access server with `ssh`

```
[user1@host_test ~]$ ssh username@domain@localhost
username@localhost's password:
[username@host_test ~]$
```

On similar configured server i can do both `su` and `ssh`.

In `/var/log/secure` i have found

```
Oct 18 16:00:00 host_test su:pam_sss(su-l:account): Access denied for user username@domain: 6(Permission denied)
```

I have checked following common Problems:

- User is not allowed to access Server.
  Is allowed cause `ssh` works.
- Wrong rights/no suid bit on `/bin/su`
  `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 32096 Jul 12 11:43 /bin/su`
- SELinux is disabled
- `root` can perform su - username
- Both configs of `/etc/pam.d/su-l` are same(i mean by working and not working server).

How can i debug this problem futher?

Comment: Possible that you are getting some sort of "local" machine lockout? did you try restarting the server just to double check or are you getting any logs that would be indicative of a physical machine lockout? I work a lot with VMware ESXI and I have had something similar happen to me before, not sure if it is the same on CentOS though.

Comment: Restart has not helped. I have it in ESXI too.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. Same behaviour